# Executing Search in custom forceCommunity:searchInterface component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, search, napili

I've seen the documentation listed at the link below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_search_and_profile.htm?search_text=forcecommunity

However this only shows how to create the input elements for the search interface. When placed in a community, there is no button to execute the search. There is also no documentation around how to implement a custom button.

I was able to isolate the event fired by the standard search component. It is  the force:searchRequest application event. However we do not have access to this event via $A. I could also URL hack it in (/search/All/Home/:queryString), but that seems to be a bit of a hack job as well.

Isn't the point of an interface to abstract this functionality? I would expect to be inheriting some helper methods that can fire the event for me.

Anybody successfully implemented one of these that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am in the same boat as you. I am trying to change the look and feel of the search bar while still using Global search but I haven't found anything yet (beside adding a button that uses force:navigateToURL).

I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: The feature is not very well developed. After going the rounds with support, the best bet is to use force:navigateToURL and hopefully figure out what 'All' and 'Home' parameters are. However, there is more baked into the search component than just the search. It also houses the pop-up 'Ask a Question' modal, so that button breaks if it is not present. Basically, only override it if you want a clean slate to work from.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation is a bit lacking, but by going through the lightning component developer guide you can achieve it. I tweaked the code snipept from the doc you linked a bit, I included a lgihtning:button and a lightning:input field as follows:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:searchInterface" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="searchString" type="String" default="@uri"/>

<div class="search">
    <div class="search-wrapper">

            <div class="search-input-wrapper">
                <span onkeypress="{!c.gotoURL}" class="slds-size--11-of-12">
                    <lightning:input class="search-input" type="search" placeholder="My Super Custom Search" label="Search" 
                                 value="{!v.searchString}" name="search"/>
                </span>
                <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Search" onclick="{! c.gotoURL }" />
            </div>
        <form class="search-form"></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my controller, I used force:NavigateToUrl, and added  the searchString value to the URL from my attribute:

```
    gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
    var searchString = component.get("v.searchString");
    if(event.which == 13){
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "/global-search/"+searchString
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
}
```

Obviously, the above fires on enter, and the button click will do nothing, however, if you add a validation for the button label or any other attribute, you can trigger the query as well.

[image]

Searching with special character will render an invalid page, you would have to add validation or convertion to Hex to properly manage this. The above is just a Prototype to get you going. Same thing goes for the CSS, too lazy to properly style at the moment this was written.